# Faster MouseClick Response?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a simple ball and paddle program in C# and using mouse clicks to move the paddle. In order to register the mouse clicks, I have this

```
    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            paddle.movePaddleRight();
            this.Invalidate();
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            paddle.movePaddleLeft(); 
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't register a rapid succession of clicks. After one click, it takes about half a second to register the next click (all clicks inbetween are lost). Is there a way for me to make the paddle move according to every click and register every click?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clicking fast produces the MouseDoubleClick event.  Use the MouseDown event instead.

Comment: Although a very old question, it was bumped by some answer. So I've upvoted, and I'd add that a mouse click in windows means "press the mouse button and release it without going out of the control", which is not desirable for a game (where you want the action to happen when you press the mouse button, not when you release it), which is just one more reason to use `MouseDown` instead of `MouseClick`